# How to scroll the whole table in Grid automatically

Tags: opentext

How to scroll the whole table in Grid automatically. 
I also have also given overflow: SCROLL to grid it was not showing any scrollbars to the GRID in viewer. 
Where in Open source BIRT it was showing scrollbars to GRID but not for Commercial BIRT. Anyone of you please help me. I am struggling with issue since 2 weeks.

Comment: what you have tried so far? show us code?

Comment: I have created a Text element and in that I have given the following HTML code: